# Redirect to Custom Error page in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In my routes.rb, I have the following:

```
  %w(401 404 422 500 ).each do |code|
    get code, :to => "errors#show", :code => code
  end
```

This creates the following routes according to rake routes:

```
  GET      /401(.:format)      errors#show {:code=>"401"}
  GET      /404(.:format)      errors#show {:code=>"404"}
  GET      /422(.:format)      errors#show {:code=>"422"}
  GET      /500(.:format)      errors#show {:code=>"500"}
```

Here is my Errors Controller:

```
class ErrorsController < ApplicationController
    def show
        Rails.logger.debug("ERROR WITH STATUS #{status_code.to_s}")
        render status_code.to_s, :status => status_code
    end

    def unauthorized
        render "401"
    end

    protected

    def status_code
        Rails.logger.debug("STATUS CODE: #{params[:code]}")
        params[:code] || 500
    end
end
```

And in my views, I have the following pages under the folder "errors"

- 401.html.erb
- 404.html.erb
- 422.html.erb
- 500.html.erb

I'd like to redirect to an error page in a controller.  If I wanted to redirect to 401, how would I do so?

Comment: all routes are pointing to the same action.. ?

Comment: yes, I included my controller above

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by adding this route to my routes.rb:

```
get "errors/unauthorized"
```

This calls the action "unauthorized" in my errors controller:

```
def unauthorized
    render "401"
end
```